# how to set the show position of datepicker?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, drop-down-menu

dear i have a datepicker inside my form.
after i click the textfield, datepicker show to up(reverse with drop down).
how do i do if i want to show datepicker dropdown not dropup?
http://img413.imageshack.us/img413/1460/screenshot5g.png

Comment: you forgot to mention jQuery in your question. Nobody will know which datepicker you are talking about. I know since I answered your last question :)

Comment: @lznogood - was this question already tagged coz I might have missed them when I last commented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look for a solution over in this [post](http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/datePickerPosition.html). Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: @Shivik: which better of that command that can make my datepicker show : down-then to right?

Comment: @klox - which jquery datepicker are you using? are you using the jquery-ui datepicker (http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker) or some other one?

Comment: @klox - Do you mean that datepicker is displayed above the textbox and not below it, like it does over here (http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/). Can you post a picture of how it is appearing?

Comment: @Shivik:i have been upload the picture

Comment: @klox: try placing the datepicker in a different place on the form. like not on top, but somewhere in between. I haven't seen such a case before so we can only try.

Answer (score 11):

```
 $('.datetime').datepicker({
     dateFormat: 'm/d/yy',
     beforeShow: function (input, inst) {
         var offset = $(input).offset();
         var height = $(input).height();
         window.setTimeout(function () {
             inst.dpDiv.css({ top: (offset.top + height + 4) + 'px', left: offset.left + 'px' })
         }, 1);
     }

 });
```

Comment: For those who want to know logic behind it [check this](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShow)

Answer (score 0):

expanding on Igor's answer. To position the calendar to the bottom right of the datepicker input element, use this:

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
    beforeShow: function (input, inst) {
        var offset = $(input).offset();
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            var calWidth = inst.dpDiv.width();
            var inpWidth = $(input).width() + parseInt($(input).css('padding'));
            inst.dpDiv.css({ left: offset.left + (inpWidth - calWidth) + 'px' })
        }, 1);
    }
});
```